# Desicion tree evaluating a 'success rate' as output variable

Tags: cart

Let's say I have a database where each case represents a person who performed a series of tests (let's say, a flip of a coin). I have couple of input variables Xi and two variables y1 and y2 where:

- y1 is the total count of tests that were performed
- y2 is the number of successes on the test (for instance, let's consider heads as success)

Note that **I do not have** data on each individual test run, only summarizes data per test subject.

I want to build a decision tree that on each node the measure evaluated is the success rate y2/y1 for the data in the node. The goal is to search for groups on the input variables that separates data between groups with high success and low success and explore with input variables (or combinations) have more impact on the success rate.

I consulted the question below and apparently there's something in there. But if someone could give me a reference, it'll be a huge help. Also, I'm sensing that I might have been missing a 'simple' way of trating my data do use this on a regular classification or regression decision tree model.

[Is it possible to build a more "controllable" decision tree like below?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35358/is-it-possible-to-build-a-more-controllable-decision-tree-like-below)

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, I was missing something very simple. The solution to this question is to prepare a database duplicating each row, creating a single output variable indicating 1 for success and 0 for failure and weighthing each row according to the number of sucesses (given on database) and number of failures (tests - successses).